# How do I call an index from a list and then mention it in print?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, indexing

I'm trying to write a subroutine in a program that will take an indexed string from a list and print the corresponding string below an if statement.

As you can see the only thing I could come up with is making a new elif statement for each and every index but that won't work because the list I'm referencing can have infinite contents. Maybe it's really obvious and I'm missing something but how do I achieve this more effectively?

```
def travelToPlanet():
  print()
  print("Please enter the name of the planet you'd like to travel to.")
  print()
  print(recordedPlanets)
  response = input("> ")
  if response == recordedPlanets[0] or recordedPlanets[0].lower():
    print("Traveling to " + recordedPlanets[0] + ".")
  elif response == recordedPlanets[1] or recordedPlanets[1].lower():
    print("Traveling to " + recordedPlanets[1] + ".")
  elif response == recordedPlanets[2] or recordedPlanets[2].lower():
    print("Traveling to " + recordedPlanets[2] + ".")
```

Comment: Your  if statements  are wrong. It should be like `if response == recordedPlanets[0] or response == recordedPlanets[0].lower():`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this functionality. If you know that whatever they type will be a planet, instead of the if-elif block, you can replace that just with `print("Traveling to " + response + ".")`

Otherwise, you can use the `in` keyword to see if a value is in the list. For instance, you could write this after the `response = input("> ")` line:

```python
if response in recordedPlanets:
    print("Traveling to " + response + ".")
```

In order to use this code, however, you must have that all the values in the list and the response has the same capitalization, so that the response can be found in the list.

Answer (score -1):

```
def travel_to_planet(recordedPlanets):
    recorded_planets = [planet.lower() for planet in recordedPlanets]
    print(recorded_planets)
    print()
    print("Please enter the name of the planet you'd like to travel to.")
    print()
    response = input("> ").lower()
    
    if response in recorded_planets:
        print("Traveling to " + response + ".")
    else:
        print("Planet not found in the recorded list.")
            
travel_to_planet(["Ping","pong"])
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.